# Android setSystemUiVisibility consecutive calls don't work

Tags: android, android-view

In my app, the user can go into fullscreen mode. In that mode, whenever the user touches the screen it will toggle the system ui visibility.

If the ui is hidden then two touches occur within about 1 second of each other (a long time in the real world), the ui is shown properly, but the navigation bar is not hidden again.  This is despite `view.setSystemUiVisibility()` being called with the correct flags to hide it.

The view in question is `activity.getWindow().getDecorView()`.

Waiting 1.5 seconds or more before the second touch correctly hides the system ui.

Flags:

```
private static final int STATIC_LAYOUT_FLAGS =
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;

private static final int HIDDEN_FLAGS =
        STATIC_LAYOUT_FLAGS |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
```

Again, to clarify, this is the expected behaviour:

1. Status bar and navigation bar are hidden to begin with
2. A screen touch shows the status bar and navigation bar
3. A second screen touch hides the status bar and navigation bar

If the time in between steps (2) and (3) is less than about 1 second, the navigation bar does not correctly hide (but the status bar does). In this case, the flag `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` is *not* set, despite it being part of the arguments sent to `setSystemUiVisibility()`.

Adding debug statements causes enough delay that the bad behaviour does not manifest anymore.

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Current "solution" is hiding the ui in an interval every 100ms until it takes proper effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800094/4449456 and found the root cause. It's protection against application that could lock device in the fullscreen mode. So navigation bar will be shown every time user clicks on screen and the system will skip your `setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION)` for a 1000 ms.